# How to create or signup user for the first time in firebase

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, firebase-polymer

I am using firebase-auth and firebase-document elements in Polymer. I am signed in with "google" as provider. My firebase database is like below:

```
firebase-app-id-location
 [-]users
   [-]user1.uid
   [-]user2.uid
```

So i am planning to create new users as they sign up using "Google". Each of the node user1.uid will contain their own details. In order to keep everyones details private i set up the below security rules.

```
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        // grants write access to the owner of this user account whose uid must exactly match the key ($uid)
        ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid",
        ".read": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid"
```

In order to test my code i have manually created a node under users using the firebase dashboard and everything is working fine. But NOW, How do user initiates the signup process? because the `users/` node is only readable/writeable to the logged in user, how do I check if the user is already present under `users/` and if not create a new new node `users/user3.uid`.
In side `firebase-document` polymer element i am setting up the location as
`location = "firebase-app-location.com/users/user.uid"`. If the user is present then my app is working fine and fetching the data. But if the user is not present then i want to create a node under users/ and load some preset dummy data.

Any ideas? How to get this working.

Comment: this might help you a bit: https://github.com/MeTaNoV/firebase-element-extended